# Sending drawn path in Apple Maps to another user to follow

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-maps

I have a small app that draws the path of a user, sort of like RunKeeper or pretty much any of the popular running apps do.

I am wondering if its possible to take that path and send it to another user via SMS, etc., so that it can be displayed on their phone in Maps and then for them to follow.

I assume this could be done as I know we can provide Maps with directions to follow but I dont see anything about taking a path drawn from Maps and sending it to someone else to be displayed in Maps.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why didn't you send it within the app, i.e. use backend like Parse and make both users see the same data

Comment: The idea is that you would be able to send it to anyone. Im trying to figure out the best way to handle this though. If you had someone friended per say in the app it would send to them in the app. But you could also if you wanted, send it to someone via SMS and just open it in Apple Maps. Thats the purpose of my question. Sorry if I wasnt more clear.